# Templates from double parametres

Tags: c++, class, templates

Here i have a template class:

```
template <class T,int N>
 class A{
   private:
    T q;
   public:
    int show();
};
```

and i want to redefine func "show" different for class int, what do i do?
in my thought it's like this:

```
template<int T,int N>
int A<int,N>::show(){

    return int(q/100);
}
```

how should i do it right?
There are alot of examples for only one template argument,but how i do define it for two or more?

Comment: You can't specialize only a single member of a template class. You must specialize the entire class: `template<int N>
class A<int, N> { // ... `.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But i want to "redefine" method of my class, or you mean i have global missunderstanding of templates,so i need to redefine full class?

Comment: Yes, if you have a template class you must specialize, or "redefine" the entire class. You cannot specialize a single method. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: you can for **fully** specialized case, but not **partial** specialization :-/